# Bind to error event of a model created by collection.create()?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone-events

I have a collection of Comments and a view which is used to create new comments. Each comment has some client side validation going on:

```
class Designer.Models.Comment extends Backbone.Model

  validate: (attrs) ->
    errors = []

    # require presence of the body attribte
    if _.isEmpty attrs.body
      errors.push {"body":["can't be blank"]}

    unless _.isEmpty errors
      errors
```

The Comments collection is super simple:

```
class Designer.Collections.Comments extends Backbone.Collection
  model: Designer.Models.Comment
```

I create comments in the `NewComment` view. This view has access to the comments collection and uses it to `create` new comments. However, validations fails in the `Comment` model don't seem to bubble up through the collection. Is there a batter way to do this?

```
class Designer.Views.NewComment extends Backbone.View
  events:
    'submit .new_comment' : 'handleSubmit'

  initialize: ->
    # this is where the problem is. I'm trying to bind to error events
    # in the model created by the collection
    @collection.bind 'error', @handleError

  handleSubmit: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    $newComment = this.$('#comment_body')

    # this does fail (doesn't hit the server) if I try to create a comment with a blank 'body'
    if @collection.create { body: $newComment.val() }
      $newComment.val ''
    this

  # this never gets called
  handleError: (model, errors) =>
    console.log "Error registered", args
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the collection event that aggregates all of the model events hasn't been hooked up yet.  That hookup happens in the [`_add()`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-73) function.  Since the validation fails before the model gets added, you don't get the event.

The only indication of failure happens when `create` returns false but it looks like you've figured that out already.

If you need the validation errors, you will need to come up with a way to get the errors to you.

One way would be to fire off an EventAggregator message inside the validator.  The other would be to circumvent or re-define the `Collection.create` function to hook the error event on the model.

Something like this?

```
model = new Designer.Models.Comment()
model.bind "error", @handleError
if model.set body: $newComment.val()
    model.save success: -> @collection.add(model)
```